# How can I control the time after an UIButton has been tapped to prepare for next action in UI Testing with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am using UI Test with Xcode 7 but have a few problems.
When I do record UI Test, Xcode translates Chinese to Unicode with uppercase 'U' and it shows errors.
And ui test code

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.navigationBars[@"\u5934\u6761"].images[@"new_not_login30"] tap];
XCUIElementQuery *tablesQuery = app.tables;
[tablesQuery.cells.staticTexts[@"\u6211\u7684\u864e\u94b1"] tap];
```

the problem is: after tapping image, there is an animation showing sidebar with UITableView or showing UIAlertController but I cannot handle the duration time. Actually, within animation the testing continues to find next elements to match but these elements do not exist or generating. So the test always be failed.
Any solution to answer this question? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you want a delay before the button action occur?

Comment: @BashirSidani tap the button -> create a delay & complete the animation -> find the button and tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with expectationForPredicate. I don't know the syntax in objective-c. But here is a part of code in swift:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.navigationBars["\u5934\u6761"].images["new_not_login30"].tap()
let label = app.cells.staticTexts["\u6211\u7684\u864e\u94b1"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: label) {
    // If the label exists, also check that it is enabled
    if label.enabled {
        label.tap()
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { error in
     if (error != nil) { assertion ....}

}
```

Just translate this code in objective-c.

Cheers